# События java

Tags: java, события

Прочел книжку "Изучаем java" и думал, что понял что к чему. Но вот набрел в интернете на урок с событиями. Вот код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Focus extends Applet {

    String msg;

    public void init()  {
        msg="";
        Font font=new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,16);
        setFont(font);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg,50,50);
    }

    public boolean gotFocus(Event evt, Object arg)
    {
        msg="Получен фокус";
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean lostFocus(Event evt, Object arg)
    {
        msg="Фокус утерян";
        repaint();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Как это работает? Где внутренние классы с имплементами, где слушатели? И вообще я удивился как это запустилось. Товарищи объясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: Это случайно не связано с родительским классом,класс апплет изначально содержит слушатели?

Comment: Апплеты умерли лет 10 назад - у них сейчас крайне ограниченная сфера использования, так что не с того начали изучение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Focus extends Applet {

    String msg;
  //унаследовано от Applet 
    public void init()  {
        msg="";
        Font font=new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,16);
        setFont(font);
    }
//унаследовано от Applet, а он у java.awt.Component
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg,50,50);
    }
    //унаследовано от Applet, а он у java.awt.Component
    public boolean gotFocus(Event evt, Object arg)
    {
        msg="Получен фокус";
        repaint();
        return true;
    }
    //унаследовано от Applet, а он у java.awt.Component
    public boolean lostFocus(Event evt, Object arg)
    {
        msg="Фокус утерян";
        repaint();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну примерно я и понял что это связано с наследованием.Спасибо

Comment: странно, что ты джаву сразу с аплетов начал, а не ООП там всякое, свинг...

Comment: для ясности служит аннотация `@override`.